# Using full calendar gcal.js I'm trying to get a day view instead of month view

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have setup a google calendar using the gcal.js from fullcalendar which displays a month view easilty enough.

What I really want to do is display this calendar in a single day or agenda view instead of the default month view but I cannot for the life of me find any reference to whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [defaultView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/defaultView/) option and set the value to 'basicDay' or 'agendaDay' as listed in Available Views.

Code should look like:
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
                },
                defaultView: 'basicDay'
            });